# There is no src attribute in my <img> after upload via custom image upload adapter

Tags: xmlhttprequest, ckeditor5

I tried to add custom image upload adapter by following official documentation on ckeditor site, copy from site and paste to my code. My image was success to uploaded. But if  I get content from my editor (using editor.getData()), I get this result :

```
<figure><img></figure>
```

The img tag haven't any attribute, even src attribute. So, how to solve this? My code exact like the code in documentation (in the end section)

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html

Comment: Did you find solution to this? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is – your server does not return the URL in the right format.

Add a console log here:

```
        console.log( response ); // ADDED

        // If the upload is successful, resolve the upload promise with an object containing
        // at least the "default" URL, pointing to the image on the server.
        // This URL will be used to display the image in the content. Learn more in the
        // UploadAdapter#upload documentation.
        resolve( {
            default: response.url
        } );
```

You should see on the console an object with a property `url`. If that's not true, then you have to fix your server implementation.